# Number Theorems

Tags: numbering, theorems

I have a very simple question, but wasn't able to find the answer on Internet. In my paper, I have two theorems: Theorem 1 and Theorem 2. However, the second theorem's number I can't put equal to 2. How continue theorems numbering?

```
\newtheorem{thm1}{Theorem}
\begin{thm1}
This is Theorem 1
\end{thm1}

\newtheorem{thm2}{Theorem}
\begin{thm2}
This is Theorem 2
\end{thm2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\newtheorem` declaration defines a *new type* of theorem, not a new statement.

In the document you use *instances* of the declared type.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
This will be theorem 1.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
This will be theorem 2.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```